# Set Cypress run browser via environment variables

Tags: npm, command-line-interface, cypress

what I am trying to do is to set browser launched when calling cypress run having this environment variables:

```
"env": {
"TAGS": "@smoke",
"browser": "chrome"
```

For example when I am calling:

```
cypress run -- -e TAGS=$TAGS,-b $browser
cypress run -- -e TAGS=$TAGS,-b=$browser
cypress run -- -e TAGS=$TAGS,b $browser
```

Nothing happens and all the time the default Electron browser is called and the tags are working fine.

```
cypress run --browser chrome
```

Works fine but I want to do it via environment variables if possible, not sure if it is and if I am missing something.

Thank you for you attention and time helping out!

Comment: With 3 of the commands you listed, you're trying to set the $browser value to env variable b. So you can set browser variable as env var and run command as - `cypress run --browser $browser`

Comment: The 3 were just an example and I want to combine several option commands.
I have set the variable as "browser": "chrome" but when I run cypress run --browser $browser I am getting:

Browser: '$browser' was not found on your system or is not supported by Cypress

Comment: Did you set the browser as environment variable before running the test? e.g on Linux/Unix system you can do it as `export browser=chrome` and then run cypress command.

Comment: Yes I am on Windows and I have an env object in cypress.json with all the env variables.

Comment: If you have it in cypress.env.json then NO need to pass as an argument when running cypress run command. There is hierarchy how cypress reads these variables. If you pass as a CLI argument, it won't read from your json file. It will try to read from your windows terminal session.

Comment: Ok so I need to create cypress.env.json and add all the variables with their names and it will get directly mapped when I run only cypress run right?

Comment: Yes works that way but only the TAGS tag is read the browser is skipped I think as Electron is launching.

Comment: yes, so you will have to pass --browser $browser option to cypress run command and in --env you can pass your tags.

Comment: Not working getting:
Browser: '$browser' was not found on your system or is not supported by Cypress. with that command TAGS are fetched successfully from cypress.env.json without the need of passing them as argument but browser is not working.

Comment: how do you set and read env vars on windows terminal? `--browser $browser` works on linux system.

Comment: The same way but for some reason it is not read from the cypress.env.json file and I don't know why, TAGS is being read without even passing any arguments.
If I manually write: cypress run --browser chrome/firefox/electron it is working.

Comment: I tried it by myself as well and it doesn't read browser value from cypress.env.json. So I think you will have to export browser value explicitly in your terminal session and pass it as --browser when running cypress run command. For the error you mentioned - "$browser not found on your system" is windows specific and I have doubt you're missing something there. Cypress official document. https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line#cypress-run-browser-lt-browser-name-or-path-gt. If you can share screenshots or some more detail I can have a look.

Comment: Yes when I am explicitly doing a cypress run --browser chrome/firefox/electron it is working. Was wondering if it can be done via env variables.

Comment: I meant to say, env vars can be set in different ways. Unfortunately, for browser variable it is not picking it from cypress.env.json. But still you can pass it as command line argument with `cypress run --browser $browser` and as previously mentioned this command works on Linux system. You will have to find a way to env var in windows terminal and how to read its value.

Comment: Not sure why it is not working and if there is a way to do this in Windows - need to research more but couldn't find anything for browser env var.